# Can some one explain how this code work in the 10th line

Tags: c++

```
//This program counts the number of words and characters. 
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h> //included for getche() and getch() 

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    int char_counter=0, word_counter=0; 
    char ch=0; 

    cout<<"Enter a paragraph(and press Enter for end):\n"; 
    while((ch=getche())!='\r')   // This line is line 10
    { 
        char_counter++; 
        if(ch==' ') 
            word_counter++; 
    }//end of while

    cout<<"\nChar count= "<<char_counter <<" ,Word count= "<<word_counter+1; 
    getch(); 
    cout <<endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please don't show code with line numbers. If you want to point out a specific line then add a comment on that line instead. Also put your question (and your thought about the issue) inside the question itself. And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to improve it (like actually having a question).

Comment: You could be more. Your question seems to be about `getche()` , have you tried reading its documentation? there are many sites like [this](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-file-handling/getche-function-c/) talking about it

Answer (score 1):

One way for understanding a complex expression, is to break is out into a separate single-line statement. Then break up each sub-expression into their own line, and so on until it can't be broken down any more.

So for

```
while((ch=getche())!='\r')
```

the complex expression that you need to understand is `(ch=getche())!='\r'`. Now put this into its own statement we have

```
auto result = (ch=getche())!='\r';
```

This can be broken down like

```
ch = getche();
auto result = (ch != '\r');
```

So then we have `ch = getche()` followed by `ch != '\r'`.

This will call the `getche()` function, which returns a character. You assign it to the variable `ch`. Then you compare the variable `ch` against `'\r'` (which is the carriage-return character).

In short, the loop iterates as long as `getche()` doesn't return a carriage-return.